# Records extract from HIVE array

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a HIVE table in which data is loaded for tripid as tripid, gps_location_1, gps_location_2 locations, it could be 10 gps locations for one trip and for other trip there could be 500 gps locations, when I query data my results are as follows

select tripid, size(gps) as count from trip;

tripid   gps_location_1 |gps_location_2 | count |

1451f2b3d |44.1145 | 44.1148|  9    |

select tripid, gps.gps_location_1, gps.gps_location_1 as count from trip;

+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+

tripid    |  gps_location_1                                                  |  gps_location_2                                          | count |

+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
1451f2b3d |[44.1145,44.1146,44.1147,44.1148,44.1148,44.1129,44.1127,44.1121] | [44.1148,44.1146,44.1146,44.1141,44.1138,44.1129,44.1127]|  9    |
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+

I can see first value from trip array table.

select tripid, gps[0].gps_location_1, gps[0].gps_location_1 from trip;

tripid     gps_location_1  gps_location_2

1451f2b3d  44.1145            44.1148

2nd row from trip array table

select tripid, gps[1].gps_location_1, gps[1].gps_location_1 from trip;

tripid     gps_location_1  gps_location_2

1451f2b3d  44.1146            44.1146

Last row from trip array table

select tripid, gps[size(gps)].gps_location_1, gps[size(gps)].gps_location_1 from trip;

1451f2b3d  44.1121            44.1127

I need to store each row in my new target_trip table like this, loop through all rows for one tripid in trip table and inserted into target_table showing below.

How can I achieve it?

tripid     gps_location_1  gps_location_2

1451f2b3d  44.1145            44.1148

1451f2b3d  44.1146            44.1146

1451f2b3d  44.1147            44.1146

1451f2b3d  44.1148            44.1141

1451f2b3d  44.1129            44.1138

1451f2b3d  44.1127            44.1129

1451f2b3d  44.1121            44.1127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lateral view explode`:

```
elect tripid, coordinates.gps_location_1, coordinates.gps_location_1 
  from trip
       lateral view outer explode(gps) s as coordinates
```

`explode()` UDTF generates rows for each array element. lateral view applies UDTF to each row  of base table and then joins resulting rows to the input rows to form a virtual table having the specified table alias.

See also [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51846380/2700344) answer for more info about lateral view.

Comment: thanks, yes I am testing with lateral view explode, now I am getting GC error ..Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded (state=,code=0)

Comment: @SM Try to increase parallelism on reducers. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42842117/2700344 Read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38475807/2700344 and this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48296562/2700344